# GuestProcessManager.StartProgramInGuest cannot run powershell block in guest os

Tags: c#, powershell, vmware

I want to run a powershell block that save last patched date to a user environment variable, but I tried both cmd.exe and powersehll.exe, only saw the processes in task manager of the guest os, but nothing appears in the environment variable.

here is the my code:

```
var userName = "name";
var password = "password";
var programPath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
//var programPath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
var arguments = "-command \"powershell \"[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('LastPathedDate', ((Get - HotFix | sort installedon)[-1]).InstalledOn, 'User')\"\"";
//var arguments = "-command \"[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('LastPathedDate', ((Get - HotFix | sort installedon)[-1]).InstalledOn, 'User')\"";
RunProgramInGuest(vm, userName, password, programPath, arguments);
private void RunProgramInGuest(VirtualMachine vm, string username, string password, string programPath, string arguments)
    {
        var auth = new NamePasswordAuthentication()
        {
            Username = username,
            Password = password,
            //InteractiveSession = true
        };

        var moRef = new ManagedObjectReference("guestOperationsProcessManager");
        GuestProgramSpec spec = new GuestProgramSpec()
        {
            ProgramPath = programPath,
            Arguments = arguments
        };

        var guestProcessManager = new GuestProcessManager(vCenter, moRef);
        var pid = guestProcessManager.StartProgramInGuest(vm.MoRef, auth, spec);

        var result = guestProcessManager.ReadEnvironmentVariableInGuest(vm.MoRef, auth, new string[] { "LastPatchedDate", "TEMP" });
        guestProcessManager.TerminateProcessInGuest(vm.MoRef, auth, pid);
    }
```

not sure where the problem is, or there is another way to get execute some script block and get the value?

Comment: "-command <something>" doesnt do what you seem to think it does.. if you do "cmd.exe -command dir" nothing happens. Im guessing this is why your environment variable never shows you probably want "/k ..."

Comment: Thanks for you post, but it still does not work. the only we way succeeded is open power policy('set-executionpolicy remotesigned') of the guest, and then use power shell run a file.'var arguments = "-command \"[pathoffile.ps1\"";'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I make it run. 
The cmd.exe cannot execute the script, but he powershell.exe could. 
the arguments which works is :

```
var arguments = "invoke-command -scriptblock {[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('LastPatchedDate', (((Get-HotFix | sort installedon)[-1]).InstalledOn), 'User')}";
```

another finding is, when you use cmd.exe, you may need to terminate the process according to your parameter. but the powershell.exe has no need to do this.

```
guestProcessManager.TerminateProcessInGuest(vm.MoRef, auth, pid);
```